# Изменить название кнопки при нажатии

Tags: javascript

Хочу изменить текст *"Показать все"* на *"Скрыть"*. Как можно это сделать?

Код сейчас просто скрывает и раскрывает блок, при нажатии на кнопку *"Показать все"*:

```js
function openbox(logo) {
  display = document.getElementById(logo).style.display;
  if (display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById(logo).style.display = 'flex';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(logo).style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="slider-main__button-read-more" id="button" onclick="openbox('logo'); return false">Показать все</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как-то так

```js
function openbox(logo) {
   display = document.getElementById(logo).style.display;
  
  if(display=='none'){
      document.getElementById("button").innerText = "Скрыть";  
      document.getElementById(logo).style.display='flex';
   }else{
      document.getElementById("button").innerText = "Показать все";
      document.getElementById(logo).style.display='none';
     }
     
 }
```

```html
<button class="slider-main__button-read-more" id="button" onclick="openbox('logo'); return false">Скрыть</button>
<div id="logo"> sample text </div>
```